# Python Tkinter: Changing the language in the macOS app menu

Tags: python, macos, tkinter

Is it possible to change the language of the entries given in the macOS App menu to German?

Thanks a lot.

[Tkinter macOS App menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xiOwz.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only change the language of the custom items you add to the menu. Tkinter doesn't provide a way to change the language of predefined menu items.

Comment: Thanks, too bad, but at least now I know that it does not work.